# Call a method with an unknown signature

Tags: c#

I'm using C# 4.6.2, though could upgrade to 4.7.2 if it's possible there.

In many places in our code we have a loop with wait statements to check for a specific value when a function is called, wait and retry if it's not what we wanted until a maximum number of retries.

I'd like to abstract this out, but the only implementation I can think of requires you pass in a method with a variable number of arguments of variable types, which after much searching of Google appeared to not be possible about 5 years ago. There has been many improvements to C# since then, so

1. is it still not possible?
2. If it is now possible how do I do it?
3. If it isn't possible can you think of any other way I can achieve my goal?

The sort of thing I'm looking for is:

```
public bool GenericLoopWait(int maxWaitSeconds, int waitMsPerIteration,??? DoSomething,object expectedResult,...)
    int maxRetries = maxWaitSeconds*1000/waitMsPerIteration;
    SomeType result=null;
    for(int i=0; i<maxRetries; i++){
        result = DoSomething(...);
        if(result==expectedResult) break;
        Thread.Sleep(waitMsPerIteration);
    }
    return result==expectedResult
}
```

And then both of these would work:

```
GenericLoopWait(5,500,Browser.Webdriver.FindElements(selector).Any(),true);
GenericLoopWait(5,500,Api.GetSpecificObject(api,objectName),"expectedOutcome");
```

Comment: Have a look at Polly - https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly; it's a good fit for what you're trying to do (with Selenium by the look of it).

Comment: I see the magic word `webdriver`, so why don't you just use built-in Wait ( https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_DefaultWait_1.htm )? You can pass a lamda to it, like `new DefaultWait(new object()){parameters}.Until(()=>lambda)`. Parameters and lambda can be input for your abstraction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use generics and `Func` and wrap the actual calls parameters when you call through to the method.

```
public bool GenericLoopWait<T>(int maxWaitSeconds, int waitMsPerIteration, Func<T> DoSomething, T expectedResult = default(T))
{
    int maxRetries = maxWaitSeconds * 1000 / waitMsPerIteration;
    T result = default(T);
    for (int i = 0; i < maxRetries; i++)
    {
        result = DoSomething();
        if (expectedResult.Equals(result)) break;
        Thread.Sleep(waitMsPerIteration);
    }

    return expectedResult.Equals(result);
}
```

Calling code:

```
GenericLoopWait(5, 500, () => Browser.Webdriver.FindElements(selector).Any(), true);
GenericLoopWait(5, 500, () => Api.GetSpecificObject(api,objectName), "expectedOutcome")
```

[Working dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8COMxq)

Comment: I thought that Func<T> doesn't allow for two different types, does it?

Comment: The `Func<T>` is getting it's type from the generic method type, which is being inferred from the type of `expectedResult`. Internally, c# will compile a version of this method for every type that is used in code, but that's all internal, and not something you generally have to worry about.

Comment: @Steve - `T` is declared at the method level which means for every call to that method `T` can vary. So the 2 lines of calling code the first can use a boolean and the second call can use a string for `T`.

Comment: but in the second call you can't have string,int can you?

Comment: @Steve - yes you can. The code above compiles, you can copy and paste it into your IDE and test it out. That is also the main reason that generics exist, so you do not have to create a new implementation (method or class) for each type you expect to use at run time if the logic is identical.

Comment: @Steve - I included a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8COMxq) with different types being used at run time.

Comment: @Igor I suspect he might be talking about needing *multiple* expected outcome parameters of different types, that vary by method being called.  If true, I would probably just go with a strict `Func<bool>` as `DoSomething`, and use the returned value as the success or failure flag.  That way, every "thing" can do whatever it needs to do to validate success.

Comment: ...Another option would be to turn `expectedOutcome` in to a `Func<T,bool>` that you feed the result of `doSomething` to, and use the result of _that_ as your success code.

Comment: @Steve - if you mean that `T` can be multiple types at once then no but this is a language restriction in general. What you could do is create a custom type and overload `Equals` and return an instance of that and well as provide an expected value to check against.

Comment: I had assumed that Func<T> meant a function with signature Function(T parameter)

Comment: @Steve - no, `Func<T>` means that it is a method with no parameters that returns an instance of type `T`

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern is to create a "Wrapper" method that accepts an `Action` or a `Func` as a parameter.  Your wrapper can do it's own logic, and `Invoke` the parameter at the correct time.

As a simple generic example:

```
public void MethodWrapper(Action action)
{
    Console.WriteLine("begin");
    action.Invoke();
    Console.WriteLine("end");
}
```

You could then do this:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;

    MethodWrapper(() => DoSomething(a));
    MethodWrapper(() => DoSomethingElse(a,b));
}

public void DoSomething(int a)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"a={a}");
}

public void DoSomethingElse(int a, int b)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"a={a}, b={b}");
}
```

To generate this output:

> begin
>   a=1
>   end
>   begin
>   a=1, b=2
>   end

For your specific case, your wrapper could take additional parameters specifying things like number of retries, time between calls, or acceptance criteria.